# Where can I go for help?

Tags: discussion

I asked two questions earlier about SP and was told they were off topic. One was about K2 and the other about Outlook, neither of which has a site on here. Can no one on here help me?

Comment: stackoverflow might be a good option

Comment: Outlook I'd say Super User if it's not programming related.

Comment: Great, thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure K2 has its own support forums. Outlook questions you can ask on MSDN.